# How can I determine what version of Microsoft FTP Service is running on Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, ftp

The server doesn't identify its version in the header so that's no help. FTP management options are available in IIS (7) Manager and there is no IIS6 Manager installed so I'm assuming it's 7.0 or 7.5 but I can't find any way to check this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since FTP Server runs within svchost.exe I found that it can be determined by checking the version of the following DLL:

`C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\ftpsvc.dll`

Mine showed "File version 7.5.7600.14294"

Comment: Also, if running in Windows 2008 R2, it must be 7.5 (2008R2/Win7). The only OS that could have v7.0 is Windows 2008/Vista (as well as it is the only one that can include the legacy FTP).